# Angular / Cordova / IOS : How to persist PHPSESSID cookie at app relaunch (using withCredentials)

Tags: ios, angular, cordova

I'm building an app using Angular 6 and Cordova 8.
I need to authenticate my users with the server so I made an interceptor to add on every requests I send the parameter withCredential set to true.

```
@Injectable()
export class AddCredentialsInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor() {
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        request = request.clone({
            withCredentials: true
        });


        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

It's working fine on web browsers and Android.
However, on IOS, every time I relaunch the application, the PHPSESSID is reset and my user is logged out.
Is there a way to persist it after app relaunch ? Maybe setting an expiry date ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was indeed to set an expiry date to the cookie on the server side.
Then, the PHPSESSID is not reset at every app relaunch and can be persisted for a certain time.